# Editing Google docs with drive API

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

(For clarity, this post relates to the difference between the Google [Documents List API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/) and [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/) on [Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/) with Python)

With the [now deprecated] Documents list API I was able to edit Google Documents by exporting as HTML, modifying the HTML and then re-uploading, either as a new document or as a modification to the original. This was useful for things like generating PDF documents from a template. I have been trying to replicate this functionality with the new Drive API (V2), however seem unable to.

Have come up with this ...

```
http = # authenticated http client
drive_service = build('drive', 'v2', http=http)

# get the file ...
file = drive_service.files().get(fileId=FILE_ID).execute()

# download the html ...
url = file['exportLinks']['text/html']
response, content = http.request(url)

# edit html
html = content.replace('foo', 'bar')

# create new file with modified html ...
body = {'title':'Modified Doc', 
        'description':'Some description', 
        'mimeType':'text/html'}
media_body = MediaIoBaseUpload(StringIO.StringIO(html), 'text/html', resumable=False)
drive_service.files().insert(body=body, media_body=media_body)
```

The above code uploads an html file as a file into Google Drive, rather then rendering the HTML into a Google Document. Fair enough, this makes sense. But how to I get it render as a Google Doc, as I was able to do with the Documents List API?

One other thing - if I set resumable=True it throws the following error on App Engine - '_StreamSlice' has no len(). Couldn't figure out how to get resumable=True to work?

And one last thing - the [sample code in the docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/python#updating_files) uses a MediaInMemoryUpload object, however [if you look at the source](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/source/browse/apiclient/http.py#441) it is now deprecated, in favour of MediaIoBaseUpload. Should the sample code be updated?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i suspect the issue is that the default for conversion has changed from true to false. You must explicitly set convert=true on the upload. See https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert

Comment: But where do you set convert=true? None of the examples describe where parameters are set.  Patching service.files().insert().execute.uri throws errors, and neither files nor insert seem to take the right argument.  The ruby version of the apiclient takes a parameters argument to .execute().

Comment: Pass as a parameter to the insert method. Like this drive_service.files().insert(body=body, media_body=media_body, convert=True).execute(). It's documented here https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert

Comment: Never mind, I answered my own question. You use something like:
`service.files().insert(body=resource, media_body=media, convert=True).execute()`